# javascript If statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to show an `alert` if the value of the `input` (`inp_val`) isn't between `minvalue` and `maxvalue` but it doesn't work, it shows the alert even if the value is between `minvalue` and `maxvalue`.

```
function compare(e){
    this_id = e.id.slice(10,15);
    inp_val = e.value;
    minvalue = document.getElementById('min_' + this_id).value;
    maxvalue = document.getElementById('max_' + this_id).value;
    console.log(maxvalue);
    console.log(minvalue);
    console.log(inp_val);
    if(inp_val < minvalue){
        alert('Minimum Value: ' + minvalue + 'Input Value: ' + inp_val);
    }
    if(inp_val > maxvalue){
        alert('Maximum Value: ' + maxvalue + ' Input Value: ' + inp_val);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function compare with an `onBlur()`:

```
echo '<input class="result_fields" autocomplete="off" onBlur="compare(this)" id="result_inp' . $idc . '" type="text" name="test_res' . $idc . '" />'
```

I've tried to do this in jQuery but is the same error. 
Minvalue and maxvalue are `input` type `hidden` and its values are stored in a DB on MySQL and retrieved with php like this:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $val_test . '" name="test_name' . $idc . '" id="test_name' . $idc . '" class="testN" />';
```

The php variable `$idc` is an incremental function `$idc++`.

Comment: use parseInt(x) on all your values ( string values)....

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Don't forget the radix `parseInt(x, 10)` :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat yup, (not needed when "use strict")

Comment: Also , it seems that chrome (26) already handle this. parseInt('010')=10 and parseInt(010)=8.

Comment: It's working! I didn't knew about parseInt(), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your integers or floats from the values you get from the text box

if they are integers:

```
minvalue = document.getElementById('min_' + this_id).value;
maxvalue = document.getElementById('max_' + this_id).value;
minvalue = parseInt(minvalue,10);
maxvalue = parseInt(maxvalue,10);
```

Or if they are floats:

```
minvalue = document.getElementById('min_' + this_id).value;
maxvalue = document.getElementById('max_' + this_id).value;
minvalue = parseFloat(minvalue);
maxvalue = parseFloat(maxvalue);
```

Comment: You should really use `parseInt(minvalue, 10)`.

Comment: There is the [Unary Operator Plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29) that can help too...

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `<` and `>` operators on integer value so parse string value to integer and then compare.

```
if(parseInt(inp_val,10) < parseInt(minvalue,10)){
        alert('Minimum Value: ' + minvalue + 'Input Value: ' + inp_val);
    }
```

Comment: You should really use `parseInt(inp_val, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(!(inp_val >= minvalue && inp_val <= maxvalue)){
     alert('Max Val: ' + maxvalue + ' Min Val: ' + minvalue + ' Input Value: ' + inp_val);
```